# How do I loop through an array (recurision) and push object key/value pairs in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

Given an array. I want to create a function recursive that loops through arr and pushes the key/value pairs in a new array (arr2) like this:

```
var arr2 = []
function recursive(arr) // function gets executed 
arr2 //will return the array with arrays
[
    [ mike, 22]
    [ robert, 12]
    [ roger, 44]
    [ peter, 28]
    [ ralph, 67]
]
```

I so far have this code but it pushes the objects into arr2, not arrays!

```js
var arr =[{name:'mike', age:22},{name:'robert', age:12},{name:'roger', age:44},{name:'peter', age:28},{name:'Ralph', age:67}]

var arr2 = []

function recursive(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    arr.forEach(function(object) {
      arr2.push(object)
    })
  }
}

recursive(arr)
console.log(arr2)
```

How can I tackle that?

**PS: since I am a beginner, please stick to my code approach as much as possible. I am sure there are way better ways to do that.**

Comment: why do you need/ ask about recursion?

Comment: no need of recursion use simple iteration

Comment: @NinaScholz don't know ... I guess because this assignment comes in the chapter recursion. As I see it, it's a simple loop but I think the exercises build up on this later and eventually become a recursion

Answer (score 1):

You can simply map like that:

```
var arr2 = arr.map(x=>[x.name, x.age]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the values of the objects. This works for object with a wanted order

```js
function getValues(array) {
    return array.map(Object.values);
}

var array = [{ name: 'mike', age: 22 }, { name: 'robert', age: 12 }, { name: 'roger', age: 44 }, { name: 'peter', age: 28 }, { name: 'Ralph', age: 67 }] 

console.log(getValues(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If not, you could map with a given keys array.

You could map the values of the objects. This works for object with a wanted order

```js
function getValues(array) {
    var keys = ['name', 'age']
    return array.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k]));
}

var array = [{ name: 'mike', age: 22 }, { name: 'robert', age: 12 }, { name: 'roger', age: 44 }, { name: 'peter', age: 28 }, { name: 'Ralph', age: 67 }] 

console.log(getValues(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `loops through arr and pushes the key/value pairs`, it should probably be `Object#entries` rather than `Object#values`

Comment: i see oly values in the wanted result set. no `'name'` or `'age'`.